# How do I fix a 3ds game card that has green stuff on the parts

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have a 3ds game that is fine on the front. It's old though, I have had it for a few years it's called "puppy word 3D" or somthing like that.

I think it's broken because there is green stuff on the gold thingies on the back (I have no idea/ forgot what they were called) I have no idea what the green stuff is so I haven't touched just in case

I might have an idea on what happened - I think I spilt some water on the card by accident years ago and water got in the golden metal things and I am not sure but I think it was near some salt that was from a salt rock lamp think

I can't show a picture of it sorry

Comment: I'd start by trying to clean the contacts with alcohol.  The green stuff is probably not conductive and it doesn't have a chance to work if so.

Comment: Can you add a picture? It might be that the connectors have fallen off?

Comment: The green stuff is likely corrosion/oxidation - copper oxide to be exact. A non-abrasive metal contact cleaner would probably work best and also work to prevent further oxidation. Failing that I've cleaned  similar gunk from battery contacts with white vinegar and a q-tip with reasonable results.

Comment: I would recommend taking it to someone that's electronics savvy.  They will have more familiarity with how to clean it.  You don't want to end up scraping the contacts off.  If you do that, the game is destroyed.